# why does this node.js code not execute in series?

Tags: node.js, sequence

I'm a total node noob and barely know what I'm doing. I'm trying to execute a series of functions in sequence, one after the other, using the `futures` library. My code:

```
var futures = require('futures');
var sequence = futures.sequence();

sequence
  .then(function() {
    console.log("one");
  })
  .then(function() {
    console.log("two");
  })
  .then(function() {
    console.log("three");
  });
```

I expect my output to be

```
one
two
three
```

but the output I get is

```
one
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js is working on callback function, so you need to pass it in anonymous to make futures execute next function:

```
var futures = require('futures');
var sequence = futures.sequence();

sequence
  .then(function(next) {
    console.log("one");
    next(null, 1);
  })
  .then(function(next) {
    console.log("two");
    next(null, 2);
  })
  .then(function(next) {
    console.log("three");
    next(null, 3);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

`futures` is moving and changing constantly. Why not use a more robust and popular module `async`. It has everything you could possibly need for these kind of operations.

What you're after is `async.series` https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback

```
async.series([
    function(callback){
        // do some stuff ...
        callback(null, 'one');
    },
    function(callback){
        // do some more stuff ...
        callback(null, 'two');
    }
],
// optional callback
function(err, results){
    // results is now equal to ['one', 'two']
});
```

Comment: I tried with async first, it had the same issue for me